# Update Slider content jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to update the slider content (image and text) when the user clicks on a specific theme. The problem is that is not respecting the behavior of the slider.

Please have a look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jp9c1xj3/7/)

## Jquery

```
// change content

var wineContent = [{
    image: 'http://magazine8.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/most-beautiful-flowers.jpg',
    h1: 'js text 1',
    h3: 'h3 text js 1'
}, {
    image: 'slide2.jpg',
    h1: 'js text 2',
    h3: 'h3 text js 2'
}];

$(".item").click(function () {

    if ($(this).hasClass('wine')) {
        //alert('wine');

        $('ul#slideshow').html('<li class="slide">' +
            '<img src="' + wineContent[0].image + '"/>' +
            '<div class="caption">' +
            '<h1>' + wineContent[0].h1 + '</h1>' +
            '<h3>' + wineContent[0].h3 + '</h3></div></li>');

    }

});
```

Comment: Why why why you don't pause the slider when the gallery is hovered? That way you'd get rid of many problems related to the timeouts and create an overall better UX

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I dont know how to do it properly